# Calculate $C= (A B_1)^{-1} - (A B_2)^{-1}$ with only $A$ and $\Delta B = B_1 - B_2$

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and two other matrices $\mathbf{B_1}$ and $\mathbf{B_2}$. I need to calculate $\mathbf{C} = (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B_1})^{-1} - (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B_2})^{-1}$. However, here is the catch: I only have the matrix $\Delta\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{B_1} - \mathbf{B_2}$. Is there a way to calculate $\mathbf{C}$ using only $\mathbf{A}$ and $\Delta\mathbf{B}$.

I already searched several Wikipedia pages, the [matrix cookbook](https://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/pubs/3274-full.html) and this stack exchange, but I could not find anything. Is this even possible? Maybe there is an approximation to this problem available?

Note: $\mathbf{A}$ and $\Delta\mathbf{B}$ are invertible in my case.

Comment: No, it is not possible.  Try inverting $B_2=0$ for example.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The matrices I have are in fact invertible. I guess I will add that to the problem description.

Comment: That doesn't matter.  Make $B_2=\epsilon I$ for arbitrary small $\epsilon$ and compare the result with $B_2=MI$ for large $M$.